# How to maintain ripple effect when the button is selected

Tags: android, selector, ripple

I have a button with ripple effect, it has two states 
one is "regular" with ripple effect and the other one is selected
the background is changed but there are two issues:

1. The hole button colored with color, I would like only to color the oval shape of the button
2. The ripple effect not persist when changing the background color of the button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/cal_selected"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/cal_day_regualr">
        <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:color="?android:attr/colorActivatedHighlight">
            <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="@color/cal_background" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </ripple>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: try this https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect

Comment: From what I saw there is no long press effect like on lollipop

Comment: use material button

Answer (score 0):

I managed to accomplish this by adding another ripple to selected state
see the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true">

        <ripple android:color="@color/cal_selected_ripple">
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="@color/cal_selected" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </ripple>

    </item>
    <item>
        <ripple android:color="?android:attr/colorActivatedHighlight">
            <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="@color/cal_background" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </ripple>
    </item>
</selector>
```